# How to Declare JaxBElement for List<Long> elements?

Tags: java, jaxb

Can someone explain me how to declare JaxBElement for `List<Long>`

```
JAXBElement<List<Long>> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<List<Long>>(new QName(""),
     List.class,long.class, pojo.getExpectedvalue());
```

Error:

> The constructor `JAXBElement<List<Long>>(QName, Class<list>, Class<Long>, List<Long>)` is undefined, it expects long value in parameter `Class<list>`

I am declaring in this way but getting error?

Comment: What says the error you get?

Comment: The constructor JAXBElement<List<Long>>(QName, Class<list>, Class<Long>, List<Long>) is undefined ,..  it expects long value in parameter Class<list>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<JAXBElement<Long>> list = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<Long>>();
JAXBElement<List<JAXBElement<Long>>> listElement = new JAXBElement<List<JAXBElement<Long>>>(new QName("apojolist"), List.class, pojo.getExpectedvalue());
```